# Difference between bloginfo('url') and bloginfo('wpurl')

Tags: wordpress

What is the difference between

```
bloginfo('url')
```

and

```
bloginfo('wpurl')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bloginfo( 'url' )` returns the value of the `home` option in the options table, while `bloginfo( 'wpurl' )` returns the value of `siteurl`.

`bloginfo( 'url' )` is akin to calling `home_url()`

`bloginfo( 'wpurl' )` is akin to calling `site_url()`

Read more in the [`bloginfo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/) docs, the codex for [`site_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) and [`home_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url), or see [This WPSE Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/whats-the-difference-between-home-url-and-site-url?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for the difference between the two functions.

A simple abstract from that answer would be:

> The site_url() `[… the value from bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) …]` will always be the location where you can reach the site by tacking on **/wp-admin** on the end, while home_url()`[… the value from bloginfo( 'url' ) …]` would not reliably be this location.